# Cannot read data from API

Tags: javascript, api

I have used openweather api in my code and whenever I type the city name then it shows me an error stating "cannot read undefined (reading '0')"

```js
app.post("/",function(req,res){
  const city=req.body.CityName;

  const url="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+city+"&units=metric&appid=c6d442adf9595680af9098f5a91497a4";
  https.get(url,function(response){

    response.on("data",function(data){

      const weather_data=JSON.parse(data);
      const des=weather_data.weather[1].description;
      const temp=weather_data.main.temp;
      const icon=weather_data.weather[0].icon;
      const imageURL=" http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/"+ icon +"@2x.png";

        res.write("<p>Temperature of "+req.body.CityName+" is "+ temp +" degrees with  "+ des+"</p>");
         res.write("<img src=" + imageURL + ">");

        res.send();

    })

  })

})
```

Comment: `weather_data.weather` is undefined?

Comment: most likely because the api cant find the city and will print a error message like this does:
 
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=t&units=metric&appid=c6d442adf9595680af9098f5a91497a4

you should check if the code is a '404' or not and then parse the data